# How can I hide an expired row in a Matrix field?

Tags: matrix, date, expire

I have a Matrix field which is being used for late availability vacancies for a tourism website. Inside the Matrix field there are two columns, Date and Description.

Rows from the Matrix field will be displayed on the front end of the site. However I'm wondering if there is a way to hide a row if the Date field inside the Matrix is expired.

It seems using `show_expired="no"` won't work as this applies to the entry itslef which won't have expired. It's specifically the Date field inside the Matrix field. If the date on the **row** is expired, I'd like it not to be displayed.

Can anyone shed any light on this please

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use **search:** parameter with combination with **{current_time}***

> {my_matrix_field search:date=">{current_time"}"}

usually date fields is keep data in timestamp format, so it must work.

*Unlike the rest of the Standard Global Variables, [{current_time}](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#current-time) is parsed very early on in the Template parser, which allows you to make dynamic use of it in your tags, for instance as a tag parameter, or in a conditional.*